# add post content in meta description in yoast

Tags: seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

How can I add post content in meta description via `Title & Metas`?

I have seen excerpt variable `%%excerpt%%` but it will give only excerpt but I want whole content in meta description.

Can any one help me for this because I can not found variable for content?

Thankns

Comment: You cannot find is because it's not there and for good reason. You are not suppose to add whole content in meta description tag. It's useless since search engines will only show limited chars. Regardless of that if you show content in meta description tag then it will defeat the whole purpose of having meta description in the first place.

Comment: I am using custom post type and in my custom post type does not have much content. Its have only one small question in content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a safe and Yoast preferred method

```
add_action('wp_head','add_custom_meta_description_box');

function retrieve_var1_replacement( $var1 ) {
        global $post;
       return strip_tags($post->post_content);
}
function register_my_plugin_extra_replacements() {
       wpseo_register_var_replacement( '%%mycustomdesc%%', 'retrieve_var1_replacement', 'advanced', 'this is a help text for myvar1' );
}
add_action( 'wpseo_register_extra_replacements', 'register_my_plugin_extra_replacements' );
```

You can now replace your %%excerpt%% with %%mycustomdesc%%

Comment: This will create 2 meta description tags.

Comment: I need a help to create new variable in yoast as like others and I think it is easier because I need this option only for my custom post type.

Comment: The best way to solve this issue, is to copy paste your content in excerpt field too and use `%%excerpt%%` in meta description.

Comment: Hi @Roberthue, you are right. I have changed the old code and added new one which we can safely use and replace %%excerpt%%

Comment: Where do I have to add these code in function.php or in single.php?

Comment: add this to functions.php and then you can use %%mycustomdesc%% just like %%excerpt%%

Answer (score 2):

In Yoast SEO there is no variable available for the content. The 2 variables that are available are %%excerpt%% and %%excerpt_only%%. The difference between these 2 is:

> %%excerpt%% - Replaced with the post/page excerpt (or auto-generated if
>   it does not exist)
>
> %%excerpt_only%% - Replaced with the post/page excerpt (without
>   auto-generation)

For a full list of available variables you can click on the "Help" tab (top right) when viewing the "Title and Metas" page of the Yoast SEO plugin.

If using %%excerpt_only%% and adding your post content in your post excerpt is not going to work for you then you could write your own function to hook into the `wpseo_metadesc` filter.

```
function custom_seo_description( $seo_desc ) {
  $seo_desc = "This is a custom description";
  return $seo_desc;
}

add_filter( 'wpseo_metadesc', 'custom_seo_description', 10, 1 );
```

I've not tested this code but something along theser lines should work. More info on the Yoast SEO API can be found here: https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/api/

Comment: I have already mention this variable in my question. I want full content on excerpt.